# How can I get the COUNT of a multidimernsional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, count

I have a class with some functions inside and I wonder how can I count how many rows are being fetched by a FOREACH loop. My array is called in the following way:

```
foreach ($this->menuIterate() as $a => $b) {
    if ($b[2] == $y[0]) {
        echo "blah blah blah";
    }
}
```

$y is called from a foreach before this one. I need to display 1 line before the first "echo" and a closing one after the last one.

I've tried array_keys but it turns my array into a 3-way multidimensional array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to count elements of the array returned by menuIterate method? Or I am not following :)

Comment: What array are you trying to get a count of? You're going to need to post more code to provide context here.

Comment: It's a triple foreach loop. The problem comes when I halt the array on a particular value and try to fetch all other values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you need something like this:

```
$arr = $this->menuIterate();
if (count($arr)>0) {

$matches = 0;
foreach ($arr as $a => $b) {
    if ($b[2] == $y[0]) {
        if( $matches==0) {    $start = 'START'; }
        $matches++;
        echo "blah blah blah";
    }
}

if ($matches>0) echo 'END '.$matches;
}
```

don't you?

Comment: Yup... that counter did it. I was trying to use one but all inside the loop so it didn't actually stop. Thanks!